# How can I access the jobs of a user-specific view of a Jenkins Server using Groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I currently have the situation that I need to trigger all jobs in status "icon-red" on a Jenkins server, which are selected by a given *user*-specific view (my-views). The problem is that the list is very long, and we don't want to trigger them all manually. 
That is why I came to the idea of using a Groovy script (Jenkins' Script Console).

I am able to trigger all red jobs of a given *global* view with coding like this:

```
def viewName = "globalviewname"
def jobsToBuild = Jenkins.instance.getView(viewName).items.findAll { job ->
    job.getBuildStatusIconClassName() == "icon-red"
}

jobsToBuild.each { job ->
    println "Scheduling matching job ${job.name}"
    job.scheduleBuild(new Cause.UserIdCause())
}
```

However, I am lacking the way how to access the current user's view (would become a parameter later on): A call to

`Jenkins.instance.getViews()`

just provides a List of all global views only. I am currently playing around with

`Jenkins.instance.getMyViewsTabBar()`

(see also http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html#getMyViewsTabBar()), but apparently I do not get the hang of it.

Any clue how to access the list of items associated with user-specific list views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed to find it out myself:

- Personal views of a user in Jenkins are part of the [UserProperties](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/User.html#getAllProperties()) of the given user.
- There may be multiple UserProperties per user - the right UserProperty is [MyViewProperty](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/MyViewsProperty.html).

Assuming that the variable `username` contains the username of the view we want to get and the variable `viewname` contains the name of the view we want to retrieve, the following prototypical Groovy coding does the trick for me:

```
def user = User.get(username, false, null)
if (user == null) {
  throw new Error("User does not exists")
}
println "Reading data from user "+user.toString()

// retrieve all UserProperties of this user and filter on the MyViewsProperty
def allMyViewsProperties = user.getAllProperties().findAll { 
  uprop -> (uprop instanceof hudson.model.MyViewsProperty) 
}
if (allMyViewsProperties.size() == 0) {
  throw new Error("MyViewsProperties does not exists")
}

// retrieve all views which are assigned to the MyViewsProperty.
// note that there also is a AllViewsProperty
def allPersonalViewsOfUser = allMyViewsProperties[0].getViews()

// further narrow down only to ListViews (special use case for me)
def allPersonalListViews = allPersonalViewsOfUser.findAll { 
  view -> view instanceof hudson.model.ListView 
}

// based on its name, filter on the view we want to retrieve
def listView = allPersonalListViews.findAll { view -> viewname.equals(view.getViewName()) }
if (listView.size() != 1) {
  throw new Error("selected view does not exist");
}

// get the view now
def view = listView[0]
```

Given all this, it's now easy to trigger all jobs in status red of this view by running

```
def jobsToBuild = view.items.findAll { job ->
    job.getBuildStatusIconClassName() == "icon-red"
}

jobsToBuild.each { job ->
    println "Scheduling matching job ${job.name}"
    job.scheduleBuild(new Cause.UserIdCause())
}
```